# keyup event not getting fired on setValue() of the textfield

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I am using two tabpanels (for e.g **T1** and **T2**). Their are two textfields and submit button in **T2** as shown:

```
xtype: 'form',
title: 'Search',
id:'searchref',                          
items: [
    {
        xtype: 'textfield',
        fieldLabel: 'reference1',
        id:'reference1',     
        enableKeyEvents:true,
        listeners:{
            keyup:function(){
                Ext.getCmp('Submit').enable();
                Ext.getCmp('reference2').disable();
                if(Ext.getCmp('reference1').getValue() == "" )
                {
                    Ext.getCmp('Submit').disable();
                    Ext.getCmp('reference2').enable();
                }                                                       
            }
        }
     },
     {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            fieldLabel: 'reference2',
            id:'reference2',     
            enableKeyEvents:true,
            listeners:{
                keyup:function(){
                    Ext.getCmp('Submit').enable();
                    Ext.getCmp('reference1').disable();
                    if(Ext.getCmp('reference2').getValue() == "" )
                    {
                        Ext.getCmp('Submit').disable();
                        Ext.getCmp('reference1').enable();
                    }                                                       
                }
            }
      },

    {
        xtype: 'button',
        text: 'Submit',
        disabled:true,  
        id:'Submit',                            
    }   
]
```

In my **T1**, I am trying to do as shown:

```
Ext.getCmp('tabpanel').setActiveTab(1);
Ext.getCmp('reference1').setValue(RefNo);
```

**MY PROBLEM:**

The keyup event listener not getting fired on setting the value of textfield from **T1**

Please help me resolve this.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Why would it fire the `keyup` event if you're calling `setValue`? `keyup` is only fired when the user types in the box.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should use change event instead of keyup

Comment: Thanks a lot.Its resovled.

Answer (score 3):

I'm posting this for historical reasons. Maybe it will come in handy  for developers working on legacy Extjs3 (I'm still writing code for Extjs 3.4).

To enable `keyup` and `keypress` events on textfiels, add `enableKeyEvents`

```
xtype:           'textfield',
enableKeyEvents: true,
```

By default:

> keypress( this, e )
>   Keypress input field event. This event only fires if enableKeyEvents is set to true.

and

> keyup( this, e )
>   Keyup input field event. This event only fires if enableKeyEvents is set to true.

Comment: This fixed the issue. Great Answer.